# How to simulate direction as well as location in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, ios-simulator, mapkit

Is there a way to simulate direction as well as location in Xcode?

I can see how to create a GPX file of locations and use this to simulate location in Xcode, and see on an MKMapView the moving location.  However if I wanted to simulate direction as well, where on the MKMapView by clicking on an MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem, I could then put it into the mode that uses direction as well as location, and the orientation of the map would rotate to align with the direction.